Resultant gravitational field due to two masses equalling zero

In this image, the point at which the resultant gravitational field is zero lies closer to the larger mass.
I am struggling to understand why because surely the larger mass has a larger gravitational pull at the point $X$ than the smaller mass, so shouldn't the point of resultant gravitational field equalling zero be closer to the smaller mass?

Put your calculation here

x would depend on the masses of the spheres not their sizes

@Thomas yes, the larger sphere represents a larger mass

Perhaps the diagram is intentionally misleading. Or the marked position of X is an error, like the typo "it zero". What's the ratio of the masses?

Thanks @PM2Ring , it must be intentionally misleading/error. The big mass is 16 times heavier than the smaller one.

Ok. So you should be able to figure out the ratio $x/(d-x)$. However, "check my work" questions are off-topic here...

@Sancol. No. Adding calculations would turn this question into a "check my work" question.

In my opinion, this question is on-topic here. It's not asking us to check the OP's calculations. The OP wants to verify that they understand the underlying concepts correctly, because the diagram in their textbook is confusing.

@Christine Is the distance d supposed to be fixed? Or are the the spheres free to accelerate toward one another?

My answer here may be helpful: https://space.stackexchange.com/a/59344/38535

Often times, it does not help to interpret pictures too literally. In this case, maybe the larger sphere is made of styrofoam and the smaller one is made of neutronium.

@PM2Ring Thank you for your help!

@LeeMosher Yes, I think I just got too confused by the diagram since gravitational fields is still a relatively new concept to me. Thanks!

@LeeMosher Or perhaps they are of same material but larger one is hollow while smaller is solid. Both of them still behaving as point masses.

Note that heavier stars tend to also be smaller in size because the gravitational pull is stronger.

Let the large sphere have mass $M_1$ and the small sphere mass $M_2$. Now consider a very small mass m between the two. For there to be zero total force on mass $m$:
$$\frac{GM_1m}{x^2}-\frac{GM_2m}{(d-x)^2}=0$$
(The minus sign because forces are in opposite directions – I'm omitting the required unit vectors)
$$\frac{GM_1m}{x^2}=\frac{GM_2m}{(d-x)^2}$$
Cancel common terms and cross multply then you can simplify and solve the quadratic for $\frac xd$ in terms of $M_1$ and $M_2$
The point of zero force will be closer to the smaller mass. For example the point of zero gravity between the earth and the moon is approximately 90 % of the distance to the moon.
As you know the ratio of the masses is 16:1 there is an easy way. Get the ratio of masses on one side and take the square root.
(In case you’re curious, there is one other place that the earth’s gravitational field just balances that of the moon so that the net field is zero. That’s about 9 meters from the center of the earth.
As you may know the rest of the earth’s mass has no gravitational effect (this was one of Newton’s important results) assuming that it’s spherical. The mass enclosed in that $9\ \mathrm m$ radius is about $4\times10^7\ \mathrm{kg}$. The gravity due to this mass of $9\ \mathrm m$ radius, on its surface, just balances that of the moon.)
